# Plugin settings checkbox

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I am creating catagory checkbox select.

My code to render the category checkbox is:

```
// CHECKBOX - Name: plugin_options[chkbox2]
function setting_chk2_fn() {

    $options = get_option('plugin_options');
    $categories = get_categories('orderby=name');  
    $wp_cats = array();  

    foreach( $categories as $category_list ) {  
        $wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;  
    }  

    foreach( $wp_cats as $v ) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='plugin_options[chkbox2]' value='{$options['chkbox2']}' />";
        echo $v;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

All catagories are rendered properly but it is not saving in database.
Thanks for reading

Comment: The reason is that there is _no code_ to save anything in the database. Write that code.

Comment: @toscho the code                                                            register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_defaults_fn');                 function add_defaults_fn() {
 $tmp = get_option('plugin_options');
    if((!is_array($tmp))) {
  $arr = array(
           "dropdown_font" => "#ffff",
           "catagory" => " ",
                    "chkbox2"=>"Uncatagorised ",
                    "text_size"=>"17px",
                    "background_color"=>"red",
                    "label"=>"Hot",


           );
  update_option('plugin_options', $arr);
 }
}

Comment: @ashraf please update your question. That would be more helpful.